# Linear Equations and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Vectors r1=[4,6] and r2=[−42,28] are perpendicular. Put M=[r1,r2], B=[−98,126]^T, and solve M^T⋅X=B by multiplying it by M on the left side.

*I'm stuck because if M is a 2x2 matrix and B is only a 2x1... How is the answer a 2x1 matrix? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, $B$ is **not** $1 \times 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r_1 = \begin{Bmatrix}4&6\end{Bmatrix}\;\;$ is (1x2)

$r_2 = \begin{Bmatrix}-42&28\end{Bmatrix}\;\;$ is (1x2)

$M = \begin{bmatrix}4&6\\-42&28\end{bmatrix}\;\;$ is (2x2) ; it is also invertible, since its rows are orthogonal vectors

$B = \begin{Bmatrix}-98\\126\end{Bmatrix}\;\;$ is (2x1)

$M^T\,X=B \Rightarrow M\,M^T\,X = M\,B \Rightarrow D\,X=M\,B\;\;$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix (2x2)

$X$ will be (2x1)